# C# how to catch Exception

Tags: c#

I am new in `C#` programming and I don't understand this problem.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{   
   try
   {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
    }
    catch(AuthenticateExeption a)
    {
        throw new AuthenticateExeption("I can not connect to the server...");
    }
}
```

I am trying `catch` exeption using my `AuthenticateExeption`, but code never go to `throw new AuthenticateExeption("I can not connect to the server...");` and program always down on `HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);` line.

Why?

Comment: Do you know for certain that the exception being thrown in the `try` block is of type `AuthenticateExeption`?

Comment: "...program always down on..." does that mean it crashes?

Comment: It's because you are getting another type of exception but you are only catching the Authentication Exception. You can add multiple catch blocks. Add just a general catch(Exception ex).

Comment: WebClient.UploadString throws a WebException or ArgumentNullException according to the docs : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: for debugging purposes why not capture the `a.Message` or change it to Exception ex and tell us what `ex.Message` is.. you want to know what the exact exception is not throw your own in this case..

Comment: Search - i.e. https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+how+to+catch+exception gives good set of articles to read like [How to catch exceptions in C# on support.microsfot.com](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/308345).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are catching the Auth Exception and then you rethrow a new version of it...

Think more like this...

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{   
   try
   {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
        if (some failed condition)
        {
           // I don't know what actually throws this, this is just for sim purposes
           throw new AuthenticateExeption("I can not connect");
        }
    }
    catch(AuthenticateExeption a)
    {
        // Handle the exception
        Log(a.Message) // etc....
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // Handle all other exceptions
    }
}
```

And from this point if you really wanted to throw the same exception you caught then you should first catch it, handle it, and then rethrow it for an external try/catch to furthermore handle.

Comment: Thank you for your replye. Solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting another type of exception. If you replace `catch(AuthenticationException a)` with `catch(Exception ex)` and add a breakpoint on that line then you can watch `ex` to see what type of exception is occurring.

Alternatively, since .Net will catch the most specific exception (i.e. most-derived type) first, so you could leave your current catch block and add an additional `catch(Exception ex)` block underneath it so that if an `AuthenticateException` occurs it will get caught, but all other exceptions will drop through to the more general case.